# Make mysql Connection threadsafe

Tags: c#, mysql, database, transactions, acid

I want to read / write into a DB from multiple threads.

After some research, I remembered the ACID rules. Do I need to call `myTrans = myConnection.BeginTransaction();` every time I want to read/write from inside a thread, in order to keep this Transaction safe from dirty reads/writes (and `myTrans.Commit();`)? In normal SQL I would use `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE` to secure it.

How do i do that in C# ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: NIT: *Connections* (the objects) are not thread-safe. ACID applies to the *SQL statements* only. Anyway, a "modern" way would generally be to use a [`TransactionScope`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.transactions.transactionscope?view=net-5.0), which accepts an Isolation Level and supports IDisposable (still should be used within a limited and probably non-overlapping scope). Setting the isolation level is different than starting a transaction.

Comment: If using `BeginTransaction` manually, [use the overload that accepts an IsolationLevel](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/6.10/html/M_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlConnection_BeginTransaction_1.htm). Per the documentation, "If you do not specify an isolation level, the default isolation level is used."

Comment: Thanks @user2864740, so when one threads begins a Transaction using serializable level on the Database, the other threads cannot start a transaction at the same time which would distort the data, right?

Comment: The *transactions* run at the same time. Any blocking occurs when *statements* from *different connections* attempt to access the same resources. (This depends on the transaction rules of course; serializable obtaining mutually exclusive locks over reads+writes). If none of the *statements* access the same resource, the transactions will not interact. If looking for specific guidance, such as what isolation level is necessary/required (if any), showing the specific query/structure in the question will be more fruitful.

Comment: That is to say: while serializable provides the most strict A-I- rules, such is not always required. It can also more easily cause deadlocks and unnecessary waits. In any case, such can be [better] analyzed with a specific query/structure.

Answer (score 3):

You only need to call `BeginTransaction()` if you need multiple statements included in the *same transaction*. It's not normally necessary for ACID rules for single statements, as individual sessions — each call to ExecuteReader()/ExecuteScalar()/ExecuteNonQuery()/Fill() — gives you an implicit transaction.

Even across multiple statements, my tendancy is to put the statements into the same long SQL string (or stored procedure) and include any needed transaction instructions as part of the SQL.

In terms of thread-safety, the best thing to do is use a separate, brand new connection object for each transaction, and wrap it in a `using` block. Connections are *not thread-safe*, and so the way to protect them is giving each thread (or transaction within a thread) it's own connection it doesn't have to share.

Even within a thread, it's better *NOT* to re-use the same connection. There is a feature called **Connection Pooling**, where the connection object you see in the C# code is a light-weight wrapper for a much-heavier actual connection that is shared from a pool. Trying to re-use the same connection object throughout a thread or application optimizes for the light thing at the expense of the heavy thing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so by using ```BeginTransaction()``` and seperate connections, the 5 threads that are writing/reading concurrently cannot lead to dirty reads?

Comment: Even if you don't call BeginTransaction(), you get an implicit transaction for each session (each ExecuteReader()/ExecuteScalar()/ExecuteNonQuery()/Fill() call), so you should be fine. I almost never use BeginTransaction(). What you have to watch for instead with multiple threads doing similar work is locking/deadlocks.